# Rewrite and differentiate between two GET parameters on the same level

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a PHP script that outputs different stuff based on GET parameters.

PHP code:

```
if((isset($_GET['channel'])) && (!isset($_GET['profile']) && !isset($_GET['c']) && !isset($_GET['b']) && !isset($_GET['highlight']) && !isset($_GET['broadcast']))){

  echo 'Output1';

} elseif((isset($_GET['channel']) && isset($_GET['profile'])) && (!isset($_GET['c']) && !isset($_GET['b']) && !isset($_GET['highlight']) && !isset($_GET['broadcast']))) {

  echo 'Output2';

} elseif((isset($_GET['channel']) && isset($_GET['c']) && isset($_GET['highlight'])) && (!isset($_GET['profile']) && !isset($_GET['b']) && !isset($_GET['broadcast']))) {

  echo 'Output3';

} elseif((isset($_GET['channel']) && isset($_GET['b']) && isset($_GET['broadcast'])) && (!isset($_GET['profile']) && !isset($_GET['c']) && !isset($_GET['hightlight']))) {

  echo 'Output4';

}
```

Current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?channel=$1&b=$2&broadcast=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?channel=$1&c=$2&highlight=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?channel=$1&profile=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?channel=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How I need it to work:
**example.com/channel/c/12345** outputs "**Output3**"
**example.com/channel/b/12345** outputs "**Output4**"

How it works now:
**example.com/channel/c/12345** outputs "**Output4**" 
**example.com/channel/b/12345** outputs "**Output4**"

Are there any clever ways to make this work like I want it to?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second capture group, you can just match b or c directly if you are looking for those literals, no need to search for any character

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([b])/([^\/]+)/?$ ?channel=$1&b=$2&broadcast=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([c])/([^\/]+)/?$ ?channel=$1&c=$2&highlight=$3 [L,QSA]
```